# fatal error, can't add my plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

I could not add my TAT contact-form plugin on my wordpress. The error that occurred:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_get_server_info() in C:\xampp\htdocs\danish\wp-content\plugins\tat-contact-form\install.php:13
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\danish\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(298): tatcontact_install('')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\danish\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\danish\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\danish\wp-admin\plugins.php(166): do_action('activate_tat-co...')
#4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\danish\wp-content\plugins\tat-contact-form\install.php on line 13`
```

Comment: which version of wordpress are you using ?
Check plugin information . If it's not compitable with your version of wordpress that these type of errors are occured.

Comment: mysql_get_server_info function is a part of deprecated mysql extension which has been removed in PHP 7.0. Your plugin is unmaintained - find a more up to date plugin.

Comment: i am using 7.3 version

Comment: got it :) thanks alot